# Android File System Mount/Unmount Notification

Tags: android, c++

I'm developing a debugging program in `Android`. The debugging program is a `native C++`
process and is a part of the `Android platform`. I need to save log to the external
SD card if there is one inserted into the Android device, and stop accessing it
when it's unmounted.

Is there any notification mechanism of file system mount/unmount? I've checked the
vold program and have not got any clue.

Answer (score 1):

A mechanism called hotplug in the Linux kernel to handle it. In the userspace, you can use the netlink socket to do detect.

When the sdcard inserted or removed, you can get the action from netlink packet.

After receiving the action, to make sure the devices is mounted or unmounted, check the file `/proc/mounts` for a mounting point.

Refer [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/hotplug.txt) for the example of netlink event.

Comment: Thanks for your information. The netlink message works when an SD card is inserted and removed. When I eject the SD in system setting, will Android inform all native processes that are accessing the SD card?

Comment: How is your native process created? if it's created from dalvik or art, check `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED and Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED`.